# FFMpeg + iOS - Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I've managed to set up RTSP streaming through the use of FFMpeg.
However, I'm plagued by some memory leaks, some of which I've managed to solve, but the profiler keeps reporting some other.

I've posted the related class on [Github](https://gist.github.com/daneov/7a21d3698266744cefb8), and would be very grateful if you could provide a hand in this because I don't know where to look anymore.

The profile reports the leak when closing the screen, so this means it is leaking something during the deallocation phase.

**Leaks:**
[image: Leaks]

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: @IanBytchek No, I tried releasing all `malloc`'ed memory and variables, using either C-functions or ffmpegs functions but always seemed to miss something :/